# OmniAuth Facebook with Devise not returning image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, devise, omniauth-facebook

I am trying to enable Facebook signup/login with omniauth-facebook for rails.  I am successfully retrieving a Facebook user's first name, last name, and email.  Retrieving the image for creation of a profile image has unfortunately not been successful.  In config/devise.rb I have: (some redactions made)

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "XXappidXX", "XXsecretXX", callback_url: "http://XXXXXXXX/users/auth/facebook/callback", scope: "public_profile, email", permissions: "public_profile, email", image_size: :large, info_fields: 'email, first_name, last_name, picture'
```

My User class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
      where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
        user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
        user.photo = auth.info.image 
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      end
    end
    ...
```

The insert statement I'm getting from localhost:

```
 SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("provider", "uid", "email", "first_name", "last_name", "photo", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) RETURNING "id"  [["provider", "facebook"], ["uid", "XXXXXXXX"], ["email", "XXXXXX.com"], ["first_name", "Erik"], ["last_name", "VandeWater"], ["photo", nil], ["encrypted_password", "XXXXXXXXXX"], ["created_at", "2016-07-12 15:07:58.509187"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-12 15:07:58.509187"]]
```

Hash returned from OmniAuth:

```
#<OmniAuth::AuthHash credentials=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash expires=true expires_at=1473523053 token="EAAYcrarZAlE8BAKuRypwRSBP2NFrFbzPXPGmJltZAfTmzJVAE68mh54f7r7srsD5uSCJZCzCSZAD7NTtRjC14qLxL95cjbSx0fuiX99999999GtzD0aGAyEE46koakFAnWazXZCYcm9QX74Og6vQQinAqZBLhrj75sK2pGLgZDZD"> extra=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash raw_info=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash email="open_umadgwb_user@tfbnw.net" first_name="Open" id="127279374371632" last_name="User" picture=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash data=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash is_silhouette=false url="https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/13614986_1999998038_6951825525819638697_n.jpg?oh=1c4e72a136a8c6d12f1bb8106593cf86&oe=582EC4BC">>>> info=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash email="open_umadgwb_user@tfbnw.net" first_name="Open" image="http://graph.facebook.com/127279374371632/picture?type=large" last_name="User"> provider="facebook" uid="127279374371632">
```

How do I retrieve the profile picture from Facebook and use it as the photo field for users?

Answer (score 0):

Use string instead of symbol in options:

```
config.omniauth :facebook..., image_size: 'large', ...
```

Comment: I added the hash returned from OmniAuth.  Apparently the image is working but is not being assigned properly in the User class.

Comment: When stopped at a breakpoint, what's in your `auth` object at the beginning of this method? What's in `auth.info.image`?